# How to stop Node.JS netlify function after completion?

Tags: javascript, node.js, netlify, netlify-function

I have written a Node.JS lambda function on netlify which creates a document in the firestore. When the funciton is called the document is added to the firestore but the problem is that the netlify function is not returning the response and the function is not stopping(as got error during `netlify dev`).

My code is as follow:

```js
exports.handler = () => {
  db.collection('collection')
    .add(object)
    .then(() => {
      return JSON.stringify({ success: true });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return JSON.stringify({ error: err });
    });
};
```

My `netlify dev` log is:

```
◈ Netlify Dev ◈
◈ Adding the following env variables from .env: API_KEY,AUTH_DOMAIN,DATABASE_URL,PROJECT_ID,STORAGE_BUCKET,MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,APP_ID,EMAIL,PASSWORD
◈ No app server detected and no "command" specified
◈ Using current working directory
◈ Unable to determine public folder to serve files from
◈ Setup a netlify.toml file with a [dev] section to specify your dev server settings.
◈ See docs at: https://cli.netlify.com/netlify-dev#project-detection
◈ Running static server from "something.com"
◈ Functions server is listening on 58955

◈ Server listening to 3999

   ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                                 │
   │   ◈ Server now ready on http://localhost:8888   │
   │                                                 │
   └─────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Request from ::1: GET /.netlify/functions/funcname
{"level":"error","message":"End - Error:"}
{"errorMessage":"Task timed out after 10.00 seconds","errorType":"TimeoutError","stackTrace":["new TimeoutError (C:\\Users\\Vaibhav\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Data\\global\\node_modules\\lambda-local\\build\\lib\\utils.js:110:28)","Context.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\Vaibhav\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Data\\global\\node_modules\\lambda-local\\build\\lib\\context.js:110:19)","listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)","processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)"],"level":"error"}
Response with status 500 in 10917 ms.
◈ Error during invocation: {
  errorMessage: 'Task timed out after 10.00 seconds',
  errorType: 'TimeoutError',
  stackTrace: [
    'new TimeoutError (C:\\Users\\Vaibhav\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Data\\global\\node_modules\\lambda-local\\build\\lib\\utils.js:110:28)',
    'Context.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\Vaibhav\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Data\\global\\node_modules\\lambda-local\\build\\lib\\context.js:110:19)',
    'listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)',
    'processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)'
  ],
  level: 'error',
  [Symbol(level)]: 'error',
  [Symbol(message)]: '{"errorMessage":"Task timed out after 10.00 seconds","errorType":"TimeoutError","stackTrace":["new TimeoutError (C:\\\\Users\\\\Vaibhav\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Yarn\\\\Data\\\\global\\\\node_modules\\\\lambda-local\\\\build\\\\lib\\\\utils.js:110:28)","Context.<anonymous> (C:\\\\Users\\\\Vaibhav\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Yarn\\\\Data\\\\global\\\\node_modules\\\\lambda-local\\\\build\\\\lib\\\\context.js:110:19)","listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)","processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)"],"level":"error"}'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving a 500 code status which means the server has a internal error. In dev mode you have a response because there is a time out of 10 seconds, after that the request finish. It could be problem of the request or the parameters.